# Как использовать "message.text" 2 раза в коде? Библиотека Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```py
@dp.message_handler(text="Promo_Code")
async def promo(message: types.Message):
    if str(message.text) == "#BLAZER":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Успешно! Ссылка на сборку: \n")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Введите действующий промокод. Например: #ABCD")
```

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_meesage(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if is_number(message.text):
            message_money = int(message.text)
            if message_money >= 5:
                comment = str(message.from_user.id) + "_" + \
                    str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
                bill = p2p.bill(amount=message_money,
                                lifetime=15, comment=comment)
                db.add_check(message.from_user.id, message_money, bill.bill_id)

                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Вам нужно отправить {message_money} руб. на на счет QIWI\nСсылка: {bill.pay_url}\n Указав комментарий к оплате: {comment}", reply_markup=buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Минимальная сумма для пополнения 5 руб.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите целое число")
```

Если пользователь напишет например `#BALZER`, то выполняется почему-то второй хендлер, как сделать так, чтобы `message.text` как отделялся от хендлеров?

Вот все библиотеки:

```py
from aiogram import executor, Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from Database import Database
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
import os
import random
```

Comment: elif message.text == '#blabla':

Answer (score 0):

Можно отфильтровать хэндлер с помощью анонимной функции lambda:

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda mes: mes.text == '#BLAZER')
async def promo(message: types.Message):
    if str(message.text) == "#BLAZER":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Успешно! Ссылка на сборку: \n")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Введите действующий промокод. Например: #ABCD")
```

Такие же действия выполнить и со вторым хэндлером. Например, если у вас кнопка "Пополнить баланс":

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda mes: mes.text == 'Пополнить баланс')
async def bot_meesage(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        if is_number(message.text):
            message_money = int(message.text)
            if message_money >= 5:
                comment = str(message.from_user.id) + "_" + \
                    str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
                bill = p2p.bill(amount=message_money,
                                lifetime=15, comment=comment)
                db.add_check(message.from_user.id, message_money, bill.bill_id)

                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Вам нужно отправить {message_money} руб. на на счет QIWI\nСсылка: {bill.pay_url}\n Указав комментарий к оплате: {comment}", reply_markup=buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Минимальная сумма для пополнения 5 руб.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите целое число")
```

Comment: Когда я использую кнопку "Пополнить баланс", пишет: "Введите действующий промокод. Например: #ABCD" Я отфильтровал хэндлеры, но это не помогло.

Comment: попробуй переставить их местами, "пополнить баланс" перемести выше

Comment: Не помогло, но спасибо за ваш ответ:)

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda mes: mess.text.startswith('Promo_Code'))
async def promo(message: types.Message):
    if str(message.text) == "#BLAZER":
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Успешно! Ссылка на сборку: \n")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Введите действующий промокод. Например: #ABCD")
```

Здесь мы используем startswith() что бы проверить что строка начинается с Promo_Code